# How to force a form tag on a button

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have a css class that defines button inside a form to be a certain way.

I'm having trouble forcing that definition on a button that is not inside the form.

is this possible?

this is the css declaration (I'm not allowed to change it)

```
form input.button{
```

Comment: Show us the css that you are using right now. Then we can help you with your problem.

Comment: you cannot do this without javascript

Comment: @Anon: yes you can: `button { style; } form button { overriding-style; }`

Comment: Sory, it's my fail. I thought that the author wants to place the button after form

Comment: @HarmWellink edited and added the declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form input.button { foo: bar; }` will affect elements of this form:

```
<form> <input class="button" /> </form>
```

If you want to target `<input class="button" />` outside of a form then add a new selector to the rule:

```
input.button,
form input.button { foo: bar; }
```

Note that the selector `input.button` creates a superset of the selector `form input.button` thus rendering the latter completely redundant, so you can make your rule like so:

```
input.button { foo: bar; }
```

...and it will render exactly the same.

#### Update:

Ah, I see you cannot change the stylesheet. You'd have to use javascript, add a new rule, or manually define the style using the `style=""` attribute on the `<input />` element, however you cannot retroactively modify an existing rule at browse-time, which is unfortunate.